# Preview image before upload the multiple images upload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm using jquery for adding multiple fields. When we select an image first time, Image preview showing perfectly. when we click add button and select an image preview not working.

what was my mistake, May I doing any wrong in Jquery script?

[this is URL of my jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/siddhuphp/v3bcqhbu/)

or

```
 <div class="form-group form-md-line-input input_fields_wrap">
                                        <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="form_control_1">Image</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-9">
                                            <input type="file" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="simage[]" onchange="document.getElementById('pre-image').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])" accept="image/*">
                                            <img id="pre-image" alt="select image" width="100" height="100" /> <button type="button" class="add_field_button">+</button>
                                            <div class="form-control-focus"> </div>                                 
                                        </div>                                  
                                    </div>


    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var max_fields      = 20; //maximum input boxes allowed
        var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
        var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

        var x = 1; //initlal text box count
        $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
            e.preventDefault();
            if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
                x++; //text box increment
                $(wrapper).append('<div class="clearfix"></div><div class="form-group form-md-line-input input_fields_wrap"><label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="form_control_1">Image</label><div class="col-md-9"><input type="file" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="simage[]" onchange="document.getElementById("pre-image'+x+'").src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])" accept="image/*"><img id="pre-image'+x+'" alt="select image" width="100" height="100" />  <button type="button" class="remove_field">-</button><div class="form-control-focus"> </div></div></div>'); //add input box
            }
        });

        $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
            e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').parent('div').remove(); x--;
        })
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your onchange event code is not getting formed properly. Append your html as shown below.

```
$(wrapper).append('<div class="clearfix"></div><div class="form-group form-md-line-input input_fields_wrap"><label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="form_control_1">Image</label><div class="col-md-9"><input type="file" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="simage[]" onchange="document.getElementById(\'pre-image'+x+'\').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])" accept="image/*"><img id="pre-image'+x+'" alt="select image" width="100" height="100" />  <button type="button" class="remove_field">-</button><div class="form-control-focus"> </div></div></div>');
```

Comment: Awesome Dude :-)